# What is the idiomatic way of looping through the bytes of an integer number in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, iteration, byte, unsafe

I tried such a piece of code to loop through the bytes of a `u64`:

```
let mut message: u64 = 0x1234123412341234;
let msg = &message as *mut u8;

for b in 0..8 {
    // ...some work...
}
```

Unfortunately, Rust doesn't allow such C-like indexing.

Comment: this code in C would be implemented behavior so it's hard to exactly understand what you want. And by the way, if we talk about strictly conforming, this code in C would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur `char` (and [`un`]`signed char`) is an explicit exception to the strict aliasing rule, so it's easily possible to write this code in strictly conforming C. The actual behavior is implementation defined, but not undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `transmute`-ing is possible ([see @Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50551721/2733851)), it is better to use [the byteorder crate](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) to guarantee endianness:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use byteorder::ByteOrder;

fn main() {
    let message = 0x1234123412341234u64;
    let mut buf = [0; 8];
    byteorder::LittleEndian::write_u64(&mut buf, message);

    for b in &buf {
         // 34, 12, 34, 12, 34, 12, 34, 12, 
         print!("{:X}, ", b);
    }

    println!("");

    byteorder::BigEndian::write_u64(&mut buf, message);

    for b in &buf {
         // 12, 34, 12, 34, 12, 34, 12, 34, 
         print!("{:X}, ", b);
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=b04a1fe2f38215605b6db37f3074c65f&version=stable&mode=debug))

Answer (score 3):

It's safe to transmute `u64` into an array `[u8; 8]`:

```
let message_arr: [u8; 8] = unsafe { mem::transmute(message) };
for b in &message_arr {
    println!("{}", b)
}
```

See this in action [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dd0fd6fcf7a822158ebfb787c5e6b50d&version=stable&mode=debug).